# How set color of points in R ggplot by function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to set color of points in ggplot and something not works.

Here is a simplified version of code.

```
library(tidyverse)

get_point_color <- function(x) {
  if(x <= 10) s <- "red"
  if((x > 10) & (x <= 20)) s <- "orange"
  if((x > 20) & (x <= 50)) s <- "blue"
  s
}

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point(colour = get_point_color(mpg)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_bw()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `case_when` since it is vectorised and `scale_color_identity` to color the points according to the name of the color.

```
library(ggplot2)

get_point_color <- function(x) {
  dplyr::case_when(x <= 10 ~ "red",
                   x > 10 & x <= 20 ~ "orange",
                   x > 20 & x <= 500 ~ "blue")
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, colour = get_point_color(mpg))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_color_identity() + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Super!!! Thanks, Ronak. I will accept it as a final solution. Very cool

Answer (score 0):

We could use `ifelse`

```
get_point_color <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x <= 10, "red",
     ifelse(
                   x > 10 & x <= 20,"orange",
               ifelse(    x > 20 & x <= 500, "blue")))
}
```

and then use the function

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, colour = get_point_color(mpg))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_color_identity() + 
  theme_bw()
```